# How to use Lebesgue number lemma?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $X$. Let $f: [0,1] \longrightarrow X$ be a loop in X. Can we find a subdivision $0=a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n=1$ of $[0,1]$ such that $f([a_{i-1},a_i])$ is contained either in $U$ or in $V$?

My book suggests that it can be done by using Lebesgue number lemma. But I cannot figure out how is that possible. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have understood.

Comment: Here the open cover is $\{f^{-1} (U) ,f^{-1} (V) \}$.

Comment: Corresponding to that open cover we can find $\delta > 0$ such that for any subset of $[0,1]$ with diameter less than $\delta$ is contained either in $f^{-1} (U)$ or in $f^{-1} (V)$. So we may take a subdivision of $[0,1]$ with norm or mesh $< \delta$. Then we are done.

Comment: This is definitely not possible if $f([0,1])$ has points in, e.g., $U$ and $V\setminus U$. Because if $f([a_0,a_1])\subset U$, then $f(a_1)\in U$ and so also  $f([a_1,a_2])$ must be in $U$ to make this possible and so on, hence $f([0,1])\subset U$.

Comment: I have just proved that $f([a_{i-1} , a_i])$ is contained either in $U$ or in $V$. I haven't said anywhere that $U \cap V = \emptyset$. I just want to say that for any $i$, $f([a_{i-1},a_i])$ is either disjoint with $V \setminus U$ or disjoint with $U \setminus V$.

Comment: You are right. I was retarded!

Comment: @Dbchatto67 You should write an official answer instead of a comment. At the moment your question appears to be unanswered in the list of all questions.